# Use Contents of Packages.config in One Project to Load Nuget Packages in a New Project

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a situation whereby I want to create a new project (in a new solution) which will have the exact same Nuget packages as an existing project.

I would like to find a way, if possible, to leverage the Packages.config file in my existing project to download those packages into the new solution. The idea being, to save me from having to run Install Package etc. for each and every package that I want to install.

Note, I am not talking about cloning a repository. Nuget package restore works beautifully in that situation. However, if I copy the Packages.config contents into the new solution's Packages.config, Nuget package restore does not bring down the packages listed in that config file.

So, is there any command or some such that I can run which will look at the config file and just go ahead and load those packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The packages.config file specifies the NuGet packages that have already been installed into the project. If you use `NuGet.exe restore solution.sln` or `NuGet.exe install packages.config` then all that will happen is that the .nupkg files will be downloaded. Your project will not be modified so if it is missing references to assemblies in the NuGet package it will still be missing them afterwards.

However what you can do with Visual Studio is:

1. Open the project with the packages.config file in it
2. Open the Package Manager Console
3. Click the Restore button that is displayed at the top of the Package Manager Console window to download the files into the packages directory.
4. Run the command `update-package -reinstall` in the Package Manager Console window.

Step 4. will cause Visual Studio and NuGet to add the references back to your project. The `Update-Package -reinstall` command uninstalls and then installs the NuGet packages back into the project keeping the versions as specified in the packages.config file.

Comment: Update-Package -reinstall will update every project in the solution, if you just want a specific project to be updated, add `-ProjectName Your.Project.Name`